# Rigidbody gets stuck "midair"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I added a physics material with no friction in order to not have my character stuck in walls which worked out great for me but, now the problem I have is, If I move my character towards a wall in a corner and jump, after my character slides down it doesn't reach the ground on corner but floats ever so slightly above it. Which keeps my `isGrounded` boolean as `false`. Therefore preventing me from jumping out of the place again.

Please note that I can freely move around in that place, but since player is not colliding with ground, it cannot jump again.

Here's the code for my basic movement:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;

    private InputAction moveAction;
    private InputAction jumpAction;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool isMoving = false;
    private float speed = 15f, jumpForce = 35f;

    private Vector2 moveInput;

    private void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();

        moveAction = playerInput.actions["Move"];
        jumpAction = playerInput.actions["Jump"];
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if(isMoving) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable() {
        moveAction.Enable();
        jumpAction.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        moveAction.Disable();
        jumpAction.Disable();
    }

    private void OnMove() {
        isMoving = !isMoving;
        moveInput = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    private void OnJump() {
        if(isGrounded) {
            isGrounded = false;
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")) {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the inspector for Player gameobject.(you can see in game view, an example of a spot where it can get stuck floating above with y position of something small like 0.0049..)

[image]

Inspector view for ground tilemap:

[image]

I already tried following:

Changing Default Contact Offset value closer to 0 in Project Settings/Physics2D, which was something not to change unless for specific needs.
Lowering the size of CapsuleCollider2D.
Switching Collision Detection mode between the options.

Comment: Don't check for grounded through collision, instead use a physics raycast down from your feet

Answer (score 1):

Going from Jay's comment, here's what I came up with in the end:

Instead of using boolean variable `isGrounded`, I instead created a new method called `IsGrounded` which takes layerMask of the ground as a parameter.
Here's how the method code looks:

```
private bool IsGrounded(LayerMask groundLayer)
    {
        // Calculate the size and position of the box cast
        Vector2 boxSize = new Vector2(GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().size.x * transform.localScale.x - 0.1f, 0.1f);
        Vector2 boxCenter = (Vector2)transform.position + new Vector2(0f, -GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().size.y / 2f + 0.1f);

        // Cast a box downwards to check for ground collision
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCenter, boxSize, 0f, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundLayer);

        // Return true if the box hit a collider, i.e., if the player is on the ground
        return hit.collider != null;
    }
```

I used `Physics2D.BoxCast` instead of RayCast in order to prevent ray from not detecting anything while on the edge of platforms.

Comment: Could you explain how you calculated the vectors, positions, size, etc. ? I have a BoxCollider2D and it does not work every time on my terrain, I would like to understand your approach.